# Tipos incompatíveis! Não é possível atribuir o valor 'NaN' à uma expressão do tipo 'real'

Tags: tipagem, portugol

Eu comecei a estudar programação a pouco tempo e não consigo entender o erro neste algoritmo

```
programa {
  funcao inicio() {
    //Variaveis
    real x, y, z, h
    x=0
    
   //Estrutura, Entrada, Processo
    enquanto(10>x){
      escreva("Digite um numero :")
      leia(y)
      se (y>=10 e y<=150){
        z +=1
      }senao{
        h +=1
      }
      x = x+1
    }
    
    //Saida final
    escreva("Quantidade de numeros que estão entre 10 e 150 :",z)
    escreva("\nQuantidade de numeros que não estão entre 10 e 150:",h)
  }
}
```

Meu algoritmo apresenta um erro onde existe um valor **NaN** sendo atribuído á uma variável real, não sei oque é um valor **NaN** e não entendi aonde estou atribuindo este tipo de valor